# Outlook Profile Picture not showing after Microsoft known issue shared on 30th SEPT

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, profile-picture

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo

I am using this graph API to get outlook profile picture it was working perfectly before 30th SEPT Microsoft has shared some known issues:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ6De.png)But some how it has stop working as before I got below error:

Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Anyone have any idea about this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about before september 30th, but recently I worked on a project and what works for me is the following:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) and hope it helps you.